# Retrieve specific items from nested array document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

I want to retrieve all the documents with their variants  except variants which has property isDeleted : true

---

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c1d023422ffef2282619192",
    "title": "Iphone 6S",
    "varients": [
      {
        "isDeleted": false,
        "_id": "5c1d023422ffef2282619196",
        "title": "Iphone 6S black 64GB"
      },
      {
        "isDeleted": true,
        "_id": "5c1d023422ffef2282619193",
        "title": "Iphone 6S green 32GB"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to write nosql query to return document like this without the second element of varients array, any help!

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c1d023422ffef2282619192",
    "title": "Iphone 6S",
    "varients": [
      {
        "isDeleted": false,
        "_id": "5c1d023422ffef2282619196",
        "title": "Iphone 6S black 64GB"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$addFields` aggregation pipeline with `$filter` to filter the `variants` by `isDeleted` field

aggregation pipeline

```
db.t4.aggregate([
    {$addFields : { 
        varients : {$filter : {
            input :"$varients", 
            as : "v", 
            cond : {$not : "$$v.isDeleted"}
        }}
    }}
])
```

sample collection

```
> db.t4.findOne()
{
        "_id" : "5c1d023422ffef2282619192",
        "title" : "Iphone 6S",
        "varients" : [
                {
                        "isDeleted" : false,
                        "_id" : "5c1d023422ffef2282619196",
                        "title" : "Iphone 6S black 64GB"
                },
                {
                        "isDeleted" : true,
                        "_id" : "5c1d023422ffef2282619193",
                        "title" : "Iphone 6S green 32GB"
                }
        ]
}
```

result

```
> db.t4.aggregate({$addFields : {varients : {$filter : {input :"$varients", as : "v", cond : {$not : "$$v.isDeleted"}}}}}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "5c1d023422ffef2282619192",
        "title" : "Iphone 6S",
        "varients" : [
                {
                        "isDeleted" : false,
                        "_id" : "5c1d023422ffef2282619196",
                        "title" : "Iphone 6S black 64GB"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

Comment: **Thank you so much**, you saved me <3